# Time series forecasting with constraints

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I want to predict the passenger flow volume of an airline route, which subjects to supply capacity constraints of the route (i.e., the passenger flow volume should not be higher than the supply capacity). Are there any algorithms that could be used to do this kind of forecasting problem with constraints?

Comment: queueing theory?

Answer (score 0):

One possible set of algorithms are for [circulation problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) that try to model the flow rate through a network with constraints.

One example algorithm is [Edmonds–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) which is relatively efficient method for computing the maximum flow in a flow network.